# VB.NET MySqlDataReader NullReferenceException

Tags: mysql, vb.net

On my application, I set up a MySQL connector and login system which queries a database on my local machine, and a NullReferenceException is thrown pointing at `MySQLDataReader.Close()` within the `Try` method. The `CheckCredentials` function worked (almost) perfectly up until the point where I recreated the function and cleaned the code in its own module.

I did some debugging and it turns out that the exception is caused by:

```
If IsAlphanumeric(Username) = False Or IsAlphanumeric(Password) = False Then
    ThrowException.InvalidCredentials()
    Return False '<------ Right here!
End If
```

Which ultimately calls everything under `Finally`, before `MySQLDataReader` is initialized. But I don't think this should be the issue, as by calling `MySQLDataReader.Close()`, `MySQLDataReader` is already defined as `MySqlDataReader`.

## Definitions

```
Private Function IsAlphanumeric(Str As String) As Boolean
    Return Regex.Match(Str.Trim(), "^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$").Success()
End Function

Private _
    MySQLConnection As MySqlConnection,
    MySQLQuery As MySqlCommand,
    MySQLDataReader As MySqlDataReader

Private ReadOnly _
    MySQLServer As String = "localhost",
    MySQLSchema As String = "gauntlet",
    MySQLTable As String = "accounts",
    MySQLUsername As String = "root",
    MySQLPassword As String = "root",
    MySQLConnectionTimeout As Integer = 20
```

## Code

```
Public Function CheckCredentials(Username As String, Password As String) As Boolean
    Try
        ' Checks whether 'Username' and 'Password' are not alphanumeric and kills the operation.
        ' Helps prevent SQL injection.
        If IsAlphanumeric(Username) = False Or IsAlphanumeric(Password) Then
            ThrowException.InvalidCredentials()
            Return False
        End If

        ' MySQL connection string containing the required information in order to establish a connection to the database. 
        MySQLConnection = New MySqlConnection("Data Source=" & MySQLServer & ";" & _
                                            "Database=" & MySQLSchema & ";" & _
                                            "User ID=" & MySQLUsername & ";" & _
                                            "Password=" & MySQLPassword & ";" & _
                                            "Connection Timeout=" & MySQLConnectionTimeout.ToString)

        ' MySQL query to select all rows within columns of 'MySQLTable' with parameters username as 'Username' and password as 'Password'.
        MySQLQuery = New MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM " & MySQLTable & " WHERE username='" & Username & "' AND password='" & Password & "'", MySQLConnection)

        ' Establishes a connection between client computer and the database.
        MySQLConnection.Open()

        ' Executes the previously defined MySQL query and reads the returned columns.
        MySQLDataReader = MySQLQuery.ExecuteReader

        ' To execute whilst 'MySQLDataReader' is open for reading the returned results from 'MySQLQuery'.
        While MySQLDataReader.Read

            ' Checks whether or not column 'admin' is set to 0 (False).
            If MySQLDataReader.GetString(4) = "0" Then
                ThrowException.PrivilegesNotMet()
                Return False
            End If

            ' Checks whether or not column 'banned' is set to 1 (True).
            If MySQLDataReader.GetString(5) = "1" Then
                ThrowException.AccountBanned(MySQLDataReader.GetString(6))
                Return False
            End If

            ' Checks whether or not strings 'Username' and 'Password' are valid matches to the returned rows' columns.
            If Username = MySQLDataReader.GetString(1) And Password = MySQLDataReader.GetString(2) Then
                Username = MySQLDataReader.GetString(1) ' Sets string 'Username' to the username as set in the table for the current account.
                Password = MySQLDataReader.GetString(2) ' Sets string 'Password' to the password as set in the table for the current account.
                Return True
            Else
                Username = Nothing ' Sets string 'Username' to nothing.
                Password = Nothing ' Sets string 'Password' to nothing.
                ThrowException.InvalidCredentials()
                Return False
            End If
        End While
    Catch ex As Exception
        ThrowException.Database()
    Finally
        If MySQLDataReader.IsClosed = False Then
            '======== NullReferenceException ======='
            MySQLDataReader.Close() : End If ' Closes the data reader.
            '======================================='

        If MySQLConnection.State = System.Data.ConnectionState.Open = True Then
            MySQLConnection.Close() : End If ' Closes the connection between the client and the database.
    End Try
    Return False
End Function
```

Comment: Duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't assign the reader until after the exception is thrown. As such it is never assigned. Therefore calling Close or attempting to access it properties throws the `NullReferenceException`.

This finally block is assuming an instance of SqlDataReader but it is in fact null.

```
 Finally
        If MySQLDataReader.IsClosed = False Then '== << it would actually be this line throwing the exception if my answer is correct.
            '======== NullReferenceException ======='
            MySQLDataReader.Close() : End If ' Closes the data reader.
            '======================================='

        If MySQLConnection.State = System.Data.ConnectionState.Open = True Then
            MySQLConnection.Close() : End If ' Closes the connection between the client and the database.
    End Try
```

So you need a null check:

```
Finally
    If Not MySQLDataReader Is Nothing Then
        If MySQLDataReader.IsClosed = False Then 
            MySQLDataReader.Close() : End If ' Closes the data reader.

        If MySQLConnection.State = System.Data.ConnectionState.Open = True Then
            MySQLConnection.Close() : End If 
    End If
 End Try
```